# error on frament listview using arrayadapter gives me error getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using listfragment where i am extending arrayadapter to my customadapter class i am getting error

```
The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}
```

Here is my adapter class

package com.arivoli.adapters;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.arivoli.amec.Contactrepresentativedetails;
import com.arivoli.amec.R;


public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private Context context;
ListView list;
private ArrayList<String> listexample;

public CustomAdapter(Context con, int layout, ArrayList<String> listexample) {
    super(con, com.arivoli.amec.R.layout.contactrepresentativelist,
            listexample);
    this.context = con;
    this.listexample = listexample;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactrow, parent, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    ImageButton i = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    tv.setText(listexample.get(position));

    i.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Contactrepresentativedetails fragment = new Contactrepresentativedetails();

    FragmentManager fm = ((Activity)context).getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

            transaction.replace(R.id.contactcontainer, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
    return rowView;
}
```

}

my main class

```
 public class Contactrepresentative extends Fragment{

    CustomAdapter ca;
    ListView list;
    private ArrayList<String> listexample; 



    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactrepresentativelist, container, false);
          list=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.contactrepresentativelist1);
          listexample=new ArrayList<String>();
          getlist();
          ca = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.contactrepresentativelist,   
                                                                         listexample);
        list.setAdapter(ca);
    }

    private void getlist() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (D)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (D)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (D)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (D)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");
    }
}
```

it displays list of items when i click on any item it should replace the present fragment for that i am using

```
Fragment fragment = new Contactrepresentativedetails();

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); 
                    // here i am getting error can any one help me how to slove 
                    // this issue 
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

        transaction.replace(R.id.contactcontainer, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
```

my imports in adapter class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


import com.arivoli.amec.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Comment: what should i do to remove the error

Comment: for adapter or in main class file

Comment: @user3069112 for adapter class

Comment: i have written my imports

Comment: @user3069112 when you have navigation drawer why would you use sliding menu. use Navigation drawer

Answer (score 2):

You need to have this `import android.app.FragmentManager;` and `import android.app.FragmentTransaction;`

And use the suggestion by Szymon which i forgot to mention.

`R.id.contactcontainer` is a container which is not in the xml inflated for adapter class

First fragment is hosted by a activity. In activity_main.xml you have a containet ie FrameLayout with id container.

Now you add your contractrepresentative fragment to it. This fragment has a listview with has a textview and imagebutton.

Now you will use a interface as a call back to the activity and then in activity replace contractrepresentative fragment with a new fragment ie the fragment of your choice.

Now in this case whichever imagebutton you click will replace with fragment2 only. Instead you can pass the position using interface as a callback and replace with appropriate fragment

Example:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Return {

    Contactrepresentative newFragment;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            newFragment= new  Contactrepresentative();
            FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.container, newFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }

         @Override
         public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
             // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
             getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
             return true;
         }

        @Override
        public void ReturntoActivity(int pos) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i(".............",""+pos);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("key",pos );

            FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
            Fragment2 newFragment = new Fragment2();
            newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }



}
```

activtiy_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         >
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment1

```
public class Contactrepresentative extends Fragment{

    CustomAdapter ca;
    ListView list;
    private ArrayList<String> listexample; 



    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactrepresentativelist, container, false);
          list=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.contactrepresentativelist1);
          listexample=new ArrayList<String>();
          getlist();
          ca = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.contactrepresentativelist,   
                                                                         listexample);
        list.setAdapter(ca);
        return view; // missing in your case
    }

    private void getlist() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (D)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (D)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (D)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (D)");
        listexample.add("Rep. Name (R)");
    }

}
```

CustomAdapter

```
   public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private Context context;
ListView list;
private ArrayList<String> listexample;
Return mCallBack;
public CustomAdapter(Context con, int layout, ArrayList<String> listexample) {
    super(con, layout,
            listexample);
    this.context = con;
    this.listexample = listexample;
    mCallBack= (Return) context;
}
public interface Return
{
    public void ReturntoActivity(int pos);
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactrow, parent, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    ImageButton i = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    tv.setText(listexample.get(position));
    i.setTag(position);
    i.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
          if(mCallBack!=null)
          {

              mCallBack.ReturntoActivity(pos);
          }
        }
    });
    return rowView;
}
}
```

fragment2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:text="SecondFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment2

```
public class Fragment2  extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
         int strtext = getArguments().getInt("key");  
         TextView tv =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         tv.setText(String.valueOf(strtext));
        return view;
    }

}
```

Snap

[image]

Now i clicked image button in row 1. so my fragment 2 displays 1. Note always navigates to fragment2

Snap2

[image]

Comment: yes i have used error has vanished but now i am getting Type mismatch: cannot convert from Contactrepresentativedetails to Fragment. i have extended fragment to  Contactrepresentativedetails this class

Comment: @user3069112 Try  `Contactrepresentativedetails fragment = new Contactrepresentativedetails();` what does your `Contactrepresentativedetails` extend

Comment: public class Contactrepresentative extends Fragment

Comment: @user3069112 and the imports in fragment class is it 
`import android.app.Fragment;`

Comment: yes it imports import com.arivoli.amec.Contactrepresentativedetails;

Comment: this is the error  The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, Contactrepresentativedetails)

Comment: @user3069112 i suggest you edit your post and add the import statements along with relevant  code

Comment: @user3069112 `R.id.contactcontainer` is a container which is not in the xml inflated for adapter class you want to navigate to second fragment on click of list item i guess

Comment: means?? i did not get you.I have written a framelayout and given id as contactcantainer.

Comment: @user3069112 then you should have a framelayout in the activity class first it will host fragment 1. then onclick you use interface as a call back to the activity and replace with fragment2.

Comment: then i should write frame layout in contactrepresentativelist xml first and can please tell more clearly

Comment: @user3069112 you have understand fragments and activities wrongly. read the docs and wait a few minutes before i post an update

Comment: ok sorry for troubling you i will wait for your reply I have a starting activity which 5 buttons when i click on button i am opening fragment with sliding menu in sliding menu i have list view when i click on list item fragment gets opened and again it is a list view so when i click on a list item it should open new fragment all the fragments are full screen fragments

Comment: @user3069112 forget sliding menu and all. learn more about fragments and activities. I will post an example with no sliding menus but it should help you understand how fragments work and how to add fragment to container

Comment: @Raghunandan +1 for the effort, you deserve that for all that helping!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
```

with

```
FragmentManager fm = ((Activity)context).getFragmentManager();
```

`getFragmentManager()` is a method of `Activity` class and you're using it as if it was part of `View.OnClickListener`.

Note: this will work provided that you pass your activity as context to your adapter. If not, replace `((Activity)context)` with a reference to your activity.

Comment: I am getting error Fragment fragment = new Contactrepresentativedetails();Type mismatch: cannot convert from Contactrepresentativedetails to Fragment

Comment: Does your `Contactrepresentativedetails` class extend `Fragment` class?

Comment: Do you have `com.arivoli.amec.Contactrepresentativedetails;` in your adapter class file?

Comment: Do you import `import android.app.Fragment;` in your `Contactrepresentativedetails` class file as well?